# read a list of classes from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with reading data from a Controller which returns JSON. Here's the code. `alert(result);` doesn't return the correct answers. I've tried many different ways, but the code doesn't work.

```
    //Controller
    public JsonResult CommentsList(int liId)
    {
        var obj = db.Comments.Where(comm => comm.Tsk.TskId == liId).ToList();
        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        
    }

    // Script in View
    $("li").click(function (event) {
        objs.toEdit = $(this).justtext();
        $("#inp").val(objs.toEdit);
        $("#edit_new").show();
        objs.liId = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: '@Url.Action("CommentsList")',
            data: { liId: objs.liId },
            complete: function (data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(result);
                $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                    //display the key and value pair   
                    alert(k + " " + v);
                });      
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: "code doesn't work" needs to be elaborated. Try just `alert(data)`.

Comment: alert(data) returns [object Object]

Comment: That is expected, as `data` is already JSON, and there is no need to parse it. So just try `$.each(data...`

Comment: So, how can I read for example atr ID from DbSet<Comment> Comments? Alert(v.ID) returns undefined.

Comment: See what the data looks like. `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` You use JSON.stringify to turn JSON into a string. You use JSON.parse to get a string into JSON.

Comment: Data looks like http://www2.zippyshare.com/v/80697583/file.html :D so errors..

Comment: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type „System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tsk_849E922A65BB899207CBDF90143C83DA7175C7A02463A2BD8DB2507E2114FC96”